# remove padding and set height, width of dynamically created button, in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to this.

I have created some buttons dynamically using android kotlin. Button position+co-ordinates+height+width, are coming from a JSON. It is all working well. I just want to remove the padding/extra space around the button text, so that button will become small.

Not able to do that. Need some help.

```
private fun createDynamicLay(xCoordinate:Int, yCoordinate : Int, buttonName:String){
    val button = Button(this)
    // Set the position of the button over the image
    val layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    layoutParams.leftMargin = xCoordinate // X coordinate
    layoutParams.topMargin = yCoordinate  // Y coordinate
    button.layoutParams = layoutParams
    // Set the button's text and any other properties as needed
    button.text = buttonName
    button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10F)
    // Remove padding from the Button
    button.minHeight = 0
    button.minWidth = 0
    button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    button.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.transparent))
    // Add the button to the ScrollView
    val scrollView: RelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.image_lay)
    scrollView.addView(button)
}
```

Comment: You _are_ removing the padding.  Are you asking how to set the height to something other than wrap_content?

Comment: I want button height width to match the text of button, sir. button is very big for now.